# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException -[AVAssetWriter startWriting] Cannot call method when status is 4

Tags: ios

I am working on video record. I use GPUImage. The error occured on iOS 10.2.0.

According the method call stacks, i found it occured randomly when call `-[GPUImageMovieWriter startRecording]`.

I searched everywhere, but all the questions are about `when status is 3` not `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the [AVAssetWriter statuses](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetwriterstatus/), you're running into `writing`. This means that you are calling `[GPUImageMovieWriter startRecording]` multiple times. This is easily fixed by checking the status of `GPUImageMovieWriter` and skipping the `startRecording` call if the status is `writing`.